# Filter comma-separated string with another comma-separated string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two comma-separated strings

list1 =  6,2

list2 =  1,2,4,5,6,7,9,12,13

I want to remove list1 elements from list2

Is there any function or anything that can achieve my desired result.

Comment: Just parse them into an array and use the usual array functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) into separate items, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const list1 = '6,2',
      list2 = '1,2,4,5,6,7,9,12,13',
      
      result = list2
                  .split(',')
                  .filter(n => 
                    !list1
                      .split(',')
                      .includes(n))
                  .join(',')
                  
console.log(result)
```